# jquery trigger doesn't open popup window work, how to?

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, colorbox

i have a small problem with a jquery click trigger. in my index.php i have at the begining of the page:

```
if ($oauth == 'yes') {
echo "test";
        ?>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#ajax").trigger('click');
            });
        </script>
        <?php
}
```

then in the body:

```
<a class="ajax" id="ajax" href="#" title="Sync">click</a>
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="login_user">content here...</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ajax").colorbox({width:"400px", height:"280px", inline:true, href:"#login_user"});
});
</script>
```

if i click on the link i get the lightbox, but if the php condition is true nothing happens, the links doesn't get triggered but the `test` gets echoed out.

any ideas on how to debug this?

thanks

Comment: I wonder if the the first ready function (`.trigger()`) is firing first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have 2 `$(document).ready` functions and the first one will be triggered first.

So the `#ajax` element isn't a colorbox yet. Try to switch the document ready functions

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't like the document ready click... As a security precaution. Try replacing with an alert function to see if the jQuery is even being executed properly, though.